# How can one save "enter key value" in a textarea, when form is submitted via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

a few days ago I was working with simple form submit, in it the textarea was working correctly! I mean the values were sent successfully to the database including `\n`. Which when using `@Html.Raw()` and `string.Replace()` I was able to get the `\n` to `<br />`.

The issue that I am facing now is that the ajax is being submitted. And all the field values are sent to the next page and response is caught! But the response is not the one I want. I mean, all the `\n` are not sent to the server so they will not be saved with other text and as a result won't help me to break the text at certain points.

What I am using as Ajax request is this:

```
function submitBasic() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax_requests/update_profile",
                data: "about=" + $("#about").val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".basic-data").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

This sends the data to the next page, I have tried using Developer Tools to learn how the request is sent. And there I came to know that `\n` is not included. That's all the issue.

Can anyone tell me, how can I pass `\n` too along with other data? So that I can get the values when I want to show?

Any suggestions are welcome! I hope I made you understand what I want, if not please comment here! I will clafiy.

Comment: so you want to send a string to server that includes \n and you want to use it in server side?

Comment: Yes, I mean first I was able to get each enter key press as \n but now I get nothing.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should do this

```
data: "about=" + $("#about").html().(/\n/g, "%5Cn")
```

---

old answer!:
first change this line of code in client side

```
data: "about=" + $("#about").val()
```

to :

```
data: "about=" + $("#about").html().(/\n/g, "<br/>").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;")
```

and then in the server side

```
var recivedData = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(about);
```

and then use it

Comment: Hehehe sorry to say, but can I get a bit elavoration of what `/</g, "&lt;"` is? I can understand that the second one is less than, but what about the first one? Are they the `<br />` tags or something like that?

Comment: what you are sorry for!?by that replacing you are doing a simple html encoding, and you can send br tags directly to server side, and you can get the idea from answer and use it for your problem

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to understand! And yes, I think using AJax I will require this, to replace the data and then write it. Ok, let me try this..

Comment: Yes, I have tried this one too! Same thing. Nothing sent to the server I mean, no `<br />` or `\n` sent!

Comment: did you try to send data as json? data: {about: $("#about").html()}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37410/discussion-between-user2675751-and-afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `\n` to `\\n` while sending it over the ajax call.

```
    function submitBasic() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_requests/update_profile",
            data: "about=" + $("#about").val().replace(/\\n/g, "\\n"),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".basic-data").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope you can now receive the `\n` on the server side and can do needed stuffs to parse it.

Comment: Nope! Its still the same ! I am not able to replace it.

Comment: Then i guess you can replace them to `<br />` using `$("#about").val().replace(new RegExp('\n','g'), '<br />')`